# Realtime email validation

Tags: jquery

Can I use a jquery script that enables checking if email and confirm email fields do not match instantly and shows a message only when they start differing when the user is typing, which disappears once they match again.
For example if the email address in the email field is: john@mail.com, then when the user starts typing in the confirm email field:

`j > no message`,

```
o > no message,

j > error message,

corrected to h > no message,
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. The `.on("input")` handles pasting too

I delegate from a container, to make sure that if the user enters one email address, then enters a confirm address and then decides to change the first address, the validation also runs

You will need some other kind of validation since my code only handles that confirmEmail is a subset or the same of whatever is in email.

So there will not be an error if both fields have the same content, for example

- `j` in both of them and nothing else.
- `john` in email and `jo` in confirmEmail

But that can be handled with another event handler, for example in the submit. Remember to REPEAT the tests on the server.

```js
$(function() {
  const $emailValidationContainer = $("#emailValidation");
  const $email = $("#email");
  const $confirmEmail = $("#confirmEmail");
  const $error = $("#error");
  $emailValidationContainer.on("input", function() {
    const email = $email.val().trim();
    const confirmEmail = $confirmEmail.val().trim();
    $error.toggle(!email.startsWith(confirmEmail))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="emailValidation">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" /><br/>
  <input type="text" id="confirmEmail" name="email" value="" placeholder="Confirm Email" /><span hidden style="color:red" id="error">Please make sure the emails are identical</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases. For example, try to type john@mail.com in the email field and start typing with any letter from john@mail.com in the confirmation feild, no message is shown.

Comment: @Bran Sorry, My bad. It should of course beet startsWith - fixed